# MySql: date and time values in UTC

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone, utc

I'm trying to set the timezone of a mysql database (5.6.10) that i'm using for development to UTC timezone. Currently the server's timezone is set to an offset of "+00:00", which I presume is using my systems local time as reference.

I could of course set an appropriate offset here, but this has the disadvantage that I need to update this offset when daylight savings time changes.

I can't find a way to just set the timezone to UTC, is there a way to do this?

(I'm converting times back and forth between utc and the mysql's timezone in my application, but i'd really like to have the same times in my database)

Comment: What os are you using? Ordinarily +00:00 means it's already set to UTC. Most os products these days have their internal clocks in UTC and convert times for display. Notice that the time zone setting only affects TIMESTAMP data, not DATETIME or TIME.

Comment: Operating system is OSX...